# TSQL How to query a Data Warehouse with the IsCurrent Flag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse

I'm trying to query a newly created data warehouse where the IsCurrent flag and effectivedate is on multiple tables.

My problem is that I get duplicate records because the Iscurrent flag and effectivedate are the same on multiple tables that I'm joining to.

How do write the query to only pull back one record and not duplicates?

I'm joining the 2 tables and need some fields in each table, but since the iscurrent is '1' I'm getting duplicates

**Table A**

```
Effectivedate   Expirationdate  Iscurrent

2015-12-09      9999-12-31        1
```

**Table B**

```
Effectivedate  Expirationdate  Iscurrent
2015-12-09       9999-12-31       1
```

**Update:**
This is a relational database, no facts and dims, no star schema.   Each table has effectivedate, expirationdate and iscurrent field.  I'm joining 2 tables and each have the same records in each of these 3 fields.  I've been exploring the RN window functions and wondered if this would be the best approach using CTE's?

Something like:  `RN =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.EFFECTIVEDATE ORDER BY A.EFFECTIVEDATE)`

My joins are

```
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.ACCTNBR = B.ACCTNBR
```

**Update 2:**

I continued to work on this and the following is working for me so that I don't get the duplicate records.

```
Select *
From Table A
Inner Join Table B ON A.Acctnbr = B.Acctnbr
AND A.Effectivedate = '2015-12-08' and B.Effectivedate = '2015-12-08'
Where A.Acctnbr = '1234'
```

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't explained your joins for us. Normally in a data warehouse you join between facts and dimensions. What exactly are you doing? please at least post the query that is resulting in duplicates.

Comment: Edited my question and posted an answer of what I've found as I work through this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY statement to eliminate duplicates, or, as you said, window functions:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.EFFECTIVEDATE) AS RN, Fiels1...
    FROM TableA A
) subq
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'll try the Row_Number windows function.  This has worked fine for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `group by` after joining the two tables by `Effectivedate` and `Iscurrent`. If you have any where clause you have to add it before the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an update to my question above, but thought I'd answer in more detail and show some things that I have learned in this process of how to query a relational data warehouse.

**If you need to query on the most current data:**

```
select * from Table A
inner join Table B on a.acctnbr = b.acctnbr
and a.iscurrent =1 and b.iscurrent =1
where a.acctnbr = '1234'
```

**If you need to query by a specific date:**

```
select * from Table A
inner join Table B ON a.acctnbr = b.acctnbr
and a.effectivedate = '2015-12-08' and b.effectivedate = '2015-12-08'
where a.acctnbr = '1234'
```

**If you need to query between effective and expiration dates:**

```
select * from Table A
inner join Table B ON a.acctnbr = b.acctnbr
and '2015-12-09' between a.effectivedate and a.expirationdate
and '2015-12-09' between b.effectivedate and b.expirationdate
where a.acctnbr = '1234'
```

**Or as:**

```
declare @datetoquery date
set @datetoquery = '2015-12-09'

select * from Table A
inner join Table B ON a.acctnbr = b.acctnbr
and @datetoquery between a.effectivedate and a.expirationdate
and @datetoquery between b.effectivedate and b.expirationdate
where a.acctnbr = '1234'
```